# Greedy Algorithm for an Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algorithms, abelian-groups, direct-product

In Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra, he mentioned about this Greedy Algorithm for an Abelian group. It's basically a procedure of expressing a finite Abelian group as an internal direct product. But the validity of the algorithm is not clear.

I included the algorithm here:

Greedy Algorithm for an Abelian Group of Order $p^n$ ($p$ is prime)

1. Compute the orders of the elements of the group $G$.
2. Select an element $a_1$ of maximum order and define $G_1=\langle a_1\rangle$.
3. If $|G_1|=|G|$, stop. Otherwise, replace $i$ by $i+1$.
4. Select an element $a_i$ of maximum order $p^k$ such that $p^k\leq|G|/|G_i|$ and none of $a_i$, $a_i^p$, $a_i^{p^2}$,..., $a_i^{p^{k-1}}$ is in $G_i$ and define $G_i=G_{i-1}\times\langle a_i\rangle$.
5. Return to Step 3.

Internal direct product requires that none of the elements of $\langle a_i\rangle$ except identity should be in $G_{i-1}$ so why the condition in step 4 is weaker?

Comment: Not everyone has immediate access to Gallian's ninth edition. Please include the algorithm in the body of the question with an [edit].

Comment: Now that the algorithm has been described, note that step 4 which you ask about is quite similar to step 2 (which you did not ask about).  The existence of such $a_i$ in step 4 can be established in a very similar way to how $a_1$ is chosen in step 2.

Comment: But step 4 has some extra requirements